# Powershell - get ad user information based on a dropdown.text value

Tags: powershell, drop-down-menu, active-directory, ldap

I folks,

I've try my best to handle a LDAP query on a button click, but I can get the dropdown2.text to search a name instead I put the complet name like "smith, peter".

What I want is, if I put any of first name or Last name in the "Manager" field, the click button will searh and return me all the corresponding value in Active Directory event if it's a name or a family name. I'm not far, but I can't find where is my mistake

```
function GenerateForm {

set-Location c:\
add-PSSnapin  quest.activeroles.admanagement

[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Drawing") | Out-Null

$form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$searchldap = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$DropDownLabel = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$DropDownLabel2 = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$DropDown = new-object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$DropDown2 = new-object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox

#Handler 
$handler_searchldap_click= 
{
    $manager = ""
    $dropdown2.items.clear()
    $manager = get-aduser  -f {name -like $dropdown2.text}
    foreach ($thing in $manager){
        $useraccountname = $thing.name
        $DropDown2.Items.Add($useraccountname) | Out-Null
    }
}




$InitialFormWindowState = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState

$OnLoadForm_StateCorrection=
{#Correct the initial state of the form to prevent the .Net maximized form issue
    $form1.WindowState = $InitialFormWindowState
}

#----------------------------------------------
#region Generated Form Code
$form1.Text = "User Creation software"
$form1.Name = "form1"
$form1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 400
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 200
$form1.ClientSize = $System_Drawing_Size

$DropDownArray = "Site1" , "Site2" , "Site3"

$DropDown2.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(125,80)
$DropDown2.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(150,27)
$dropdown2.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$dropdown2.TabIndex = 5
$dropdown2.Name = "dropdown2"
$DropDown2.add_TextUpdate({ Write-Host "TextUpdate. Updated text is: $($Dropdown2.Text)" })
$Form1.Controls.Add($DropDown2)

$DropDownLabel2 = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$DropDownLabel2.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(50,80)
$DropDownLabel2.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(50,27)
$DropDownLabel2.Text = "Manager:"
$Form1.Controls.Add($DropDownLabel2)

$DropDown.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(125,55)
$DropDown.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(150,27)
$dropdown.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$dropdown.TabIndex = 4
$dropdown.Name = "dropdown1"

$DropDownLabel = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$DropDownLabel.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(50,58)
$DropDownLabel.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(50,27)
$DropDownLabel.Text = "Location:"

$Form1.Controls.Add($DropDown)
$Form1.Controls.Add($DropDownLabel)

ForEach ($Item in $DropDownArray) {
$DropDown.Items.Add($Item) | Out-Null
}

###Button section

$searchldap.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(275,80)
$searchldap.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,20)
$searchldap.Text = "Search"
$searchldap.Add_Click($handler_searchldap_click)

$Form1.Controls.Add($searchldap)

#Save the initial state of the form
$InitialFormWindowState = $form1.WindowState
#Init the OnLoad event to correct the initial state of the form
$form1.add_Load($OnLoadForm_StateCorrection)
#Show the Form
$form1.ShowDialog()| Out-Null
} #end of function
GenerateForm
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the quest-cmdlets. Have you tried searching with: `Get-ADUser -DisplayName "*$($dropdown2.text)*"` ? This question depends on what fields you use in your AD, but `displayname` is usually fullname like "Lastname FirstName"

Comment: @Graimer `get-aduser` isn't a Quest cmdlet but  `get-qaduser` is.. ;)

Comment: well then that's his first error, because he loads the quest-snapin, not the AD-module from microsoft :P

Comment: Ho my module is loaded, sorry that's my "test" script for posting. On my full script the module is loaded

Comment: Thanks for your time guys it's appreciated. I'm learning everytime you take time to explain me something have a nice weekend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$filter = [scriptblock]::Create("Name -like '*$($dropdown2.text)*'")
$manager = get-aduser  -f $filter
```

Powershell does not expand local variables used in filter script blocks before it passes them to the DC (via the AD Gateway Service).  To get around that, create the filter script block from an expandable string

Comment: thanks that's something I need to read about. But it worked like a charm. Thanks